# how to use rtkquery hook inside create async thunk

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, rtk-query

I am building cart functionality for my app, i created rtk query hooks for All features such as adding, deleting, getall for cart items how to pass these hooks to createasyncthunk

i tried to pass it like this

```
export const getCartItems=createAsyncThunk(useGetAllCartItemsQuery(userLToken),async()=>{
    const response=await useGetAllCartItemsQuery()
    console.log('cartResponse',response);
})

    extraReducers(builder){
             builder
                    .addCase(getCartItems.pending,(state,action)=>{
                        state.status="loading"
                    })
                    .addCase(getCartItems.fulfilled,(state,action)=>{
                        state.status="succeded"
                        state.itemsList.push(action.payload)
                        console.log(action.payload)
                    })
                    .addCase(getCartItems.rejected,(state,action)=>{
                        state.status="failed"
                        state.error=action.error.message;
                    })
                  
    }
```

i am trying to pass like this is this the right way?  i am getting bunch of errors if i add the above code in my cart slice

Comment: Why are you doing this? RTK Query uses createAsyncThunk internally, and it does everything you are trying to do here internally as well - it looks like you are trying to do it the other way round. What is your goal with this?

Comment: Sir I am doing this for Maintaining Cart Data , Same Copy on Redux store and Back end DB. Every time One clicks Add to cart or Remove or refresh cart data everytime a chage happens , if rtk query does this on it's own . then " how to connect it to redux store " and maintain a copy of cart details on redux and db while maintaining the sync , "How to connect rtk query to redux store"?

Comment: The purpose of RTK Query in general is to always keep the client in sync with what is happening on the server. 
You would use `invalidateTags` to refresh the query data on the client every time a mutation changes it on the server. See Chaper 7 and 8 of [the official Redux Tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-7-rtk-query-basics).
There is no need to manually put this into the Redux store - that is take care of for you by the RTK Query slice. Just use your `useCartDataQuery` eveywhere you need your cart contents.